# This video element does not have a mechanism that allows an accessible name value to be calculated

Tags: html, html5-video, accessibility

I have the following code, which was rendered in AEM, but cannot understand what exactly needs to be corrected to resolve this accessibility report error:

"This video element does not have a mechanism that allows an accessible name value to be calculated. Ensure embedded objects are directly accessible [WEB-60]"

```
<video playsinline="" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" width="100%"/>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" data-src="video.mp4"/>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/webm" data-src="video.mp4"/>
  sorry, your browser doesn&#039;t support embedded videos.
</video/>
```

Could it be the empty attributes that are causing the issue (playsinline="" loop="" autoplay="")?

Comment: The HTML code here is invalid, there are slashes at the end of all tags. These self-closing tags must only be used for [void elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element) like `<source>`. `<video>` is none of them. This might also be a cause for automated testing errors.

Comment: @Andy, oops, I just copy/pasted the original sample code in my answer and didn't really look at the closing slash.  Thanks for fixing the OP and my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the video player itself does not have to be a focusable element, which means it doesn't really need an accessible name.  All the controls **within** the video player (play, pause, mute, settings, etc) **do** need an accessible name.

But if keyboard focus can move to the video player, then just add an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) to the video.

```
<video aria-label="subject of the video" playsinline="" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" width="100%">
...
</video>
```

If you have text elsewhere on your page that has the title of the video, then you can use [`aria-labelledby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-labelledby) instead.

```
<h2 id="newID">kittens and puppies</h2>
...
<video aria-labelledby="newID" playsinline="" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" width="100%">
...
</video>
```